# Changing defined size in a function

Tags: c

Trying to get more familiar with arrays in C, but I have ran in to a problem. At the start of the program I define array column and row size:

```
#define rows 10
#define cols 20
```

Have several functions which work with the array everything is fine.
However, I might need to add a function that changes the defined rows and cols for exaple to 5 and 10. So is there any way to do so in the function itself without changing the numbers at the top of the code where I defined them the first time.

Answer (score 1):

When you use [`#define`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/teas0593%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you are not creating variables per se. Rather, every spot at which the token `rows` or `cols` is used, `10` and `20` (respectively) will be *textually substituted*. Therefore, it makes no sense to "reassign `rows` or `cols`", since it would be similar to trying to assign a value to `10` or `20`. If you need such a reassignment capability, use regular variables instead.

Comment: +1, but of course if they are in pre C99 they will not be able to use VLA's

Comment: @GradyPlayer: And a VLA's size can't be changed at runtime after its definition anyway.